# Email getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: jquery

I'm having this snippet of code which checks if an email is available or not. There is an error which I couldn't find a way around it. It's not a critical error but I want my snip to be error-free:

```
//em defined above this snip
$("#email").change(function() {
    var e = $("#email").val();
    var eregex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if(eregex.test(e)){
        em.removeClass("text-danger");
        em.addClass("text-warning");
        setTimeout(em.text("Email valid. Checking."),500);
 //1
      $.get("/box/check.php?m=2&q="+encodeURIComponent(e),function(data,status) {
 //2
        if(!(data=="0")) {
            em.text("Oops! This email is already registered.");
        } else {
            em.text("Great!");
        }
      });
    } else {
            em.text("Email is invalid.");
    }
});
```

I tracked down the error and it seems that is happens between the //1 and //2 commented above.

I keep having : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on my Chrome Dev Console.

If I put `var e = encodeURIComponent(e);`, the regex wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: Always works. 200 OK.

Comment: Above this code is checking the username which is the same (but no regex up there) and it works fine, no error. I doubt the @ which messes this up.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { em.text("Email valid. Checking.") },500);` but only if em is global

Comment: What's wrong with the setTimeout?? I can't find the problem.

Comment: Side note: you don't need to encode params yourself, jQuery can do it for you.

Comment: em is already global.

Comment: @mplungjan It works. Thanks. I forgot to wrap it in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the problem is `setTimeout(em.text("Email valid. Checking."),500);`.

setTimeout expects a function (or a string it can eval) to execute after a delay. This code will evaluate, and return a jQuery object. When the setTimeout tries to execute this object, you get your error. Removing the timeout, and just having `em.text("Email valid. Checking.");` on that line *should* fix the problem I think

Comment: Or wrap it in a function, if you do indeed want to display the message after half a second

Comment: Oh Thanks! I wanted to do a dot loading animation but I forgot what was it about. Now, fixed.

Comment: I guess I should have answered instead of commenting

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to be a bit more explicit about what was going on, and why :)